# Update one column based on count of records of grouped value in another column

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, update

Given a table

```
CREATE TABLE TABLE_ITEMS (
    serial_num int null,
    item_group int null
 );

INSERT INTO TABLE_ITEMS
VALUES 
 (0,1), (1,1), (2,1), (3,1), (4,1),
 (0,2), (1,2), (2,2), (3,2), (4,2), (5,2), 
 (0,3), (1,3), (2,3);
```

and so on...

I need to know how to run a query which will update the rows with `0` as the `serial_num` to be the next number in the `serial_num` sequence for the given `item_group`

The result will look like this:

```
   those were the zeroes
   ↓
(**5**,1) (1,1) (2,1) (3,1) (4,1) 
(**6**,2) (1,2) (2,2) (3,2) (4,2) (5,2) 
(**3**,3) (1,3) (2,3)
```

I want to update an item in `serial_num=0` to be the last `serial_num` plus 1 (if the last one was 70, it needs to be 71).

How can I do it?

Comment: I attempted to answer as best as I can understand the question but it would help if you could add some details or an example.  Don't know what you mean by "need it to a different item_group at once"

Comment: I'm voting to close unless you clarify the question with an example as @Thronk suggested. I'm a native English speaker and find your question difficult to understand.

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? Postgres? Oracle?

Comment: When providing table designs and sample data, you should include actual `CREATE TABLE` and `INSERT` statements, so that anyone trying to answer could easily reproduce your problem.

Comment: @Paul-White  Why was this edited to remove the SQL tag?  It is a question about how to write a given SQL update statement.

Comment: Since the question is on hold I'll add an guess as a comment: `update table_items t1 set serial_num = (select max(serial_num) + 1 from table_items t2 where t1.item_group = t2.item_group) where serial_num = 0`

Answer (score 1):

```
CREATE TABLE TABLE_ITEMS (
    serial_num int null,
    item_group int null
 )
 GO

INSERT INTO TABLE_ITEMS
VALUES 
(0,1), (1,1), (2,1),(3,1) ,(4,1) ,(0,2) ,(1,2), (2,2), (3,2), (4,2), (5,2), (0,3) ,(1,3) ,(2,3)
GO

SELECT 
    Item_group, 
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY item_group order by item_group) AS AddNum 
INTO #NewSerials
from TABLE_ITEMS 
WHERE serial_num <> 0

SELECT * FROM TABLE_ITEMS

;WITH CTE AS 
(SELECT MAX(addnum) as addnum, item_group from #NewSerials group by item_group)
UPDATE ti
    SET ti.serial_num = CTE.AddNum
FROM TABLE_ITEMS ti
JOIN CTE ON CTE.item_group = ti.item_group
WHERE ti.serial_num = 0

SELECT * FROM TABLE_ITEMS

5   1
1   1
2   1
3   1
4   1
6   2
1   2
2   2
3   2
4   2
5   2
3   3
1   3
2   3
```

Comment: the table looks like this:
(0,1)
(1,1)
(2,1)
(3,1)
(4,1)
(0,2)
(1,2)
(2,2)
(3,2)
(4,2)
(5,2)
(0,3)
(1,3)
(2,3)
and so on...

so I need to look like this:
(5,1)
(1,1)
(2,1)
(3,1)
(4,1)
(6,2)
(1,2)
(2,2)
(3,2)
(4,2)
(5,2)
(3,3)
(1,3)
(2,3)

Comment: @student - I used your comment to edit your question in the hopes it can be salvaged from the "hold" status.  Also edited my answer to match your expected result.  Does it now answer your question?